# On the assumptions of Hommel, Rom and Hochberg corrections for FWER control

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, assumptions

First of all, I looked up similar questions here before posting but those were unanswered, so I'll ask again.

My major is Biology but I also hold a MSc in Bioinformatics, so it is in my best interests to keep learning the ins and outs of Statistics. As stated in the documentation of the `p.adjust` command in R<sup>1</sup>:

> Hochberg's and Hommel's methods are valid when the hypothesis tests are independent or when they are non-negatively associated (Sarkar, 1998; Sarkar and Chang, 1997).

After reading Shaffer's review of multiple hypothesis testing methods<sup>2</sup> and Sarkar (1998)<sup>3</sup>, it is clear to me that situations where the test statistics are negatively associated are few, but **what does it really mean that those hypothesis tests are negatively associated?** Could somebody give a brief example/ use case?

Bibliography:

1. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/p.adjust
2. J. P. Shaffer (1995). Multiple Hypothesis Testing. Annual Review of Psychology, Vol. 46:561-584. https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.ps.46.020195.003021
3. Sarkar, S. (1998). Some probability inequalities for ordered MTP2 random variables: a proof of Simes conjecture. Annals of Statistics, 26, 494--504. 10.1214/aos/1028144846.